# FuelPHP でリクエストごとに固有のIDを生成する方法

Tags: fuelphp

コントローラー内でリクエストのログをS3に保存したいのですが
それなりに数が多くなる（１サーバーあたり秒間数十件、全サーバーから数百件)ことが予想され
同じファイルに書き込むと　ロック⇒追記⇒かき戻し　とやってるとネックになる恐れがあるので
リクエストごとに別のS3ファイルとして保存したいです
（定期的に過去分を１ファイルにまとめるバッチを走らせてAthenaでみることを想定）

そこでかぶらないS3パスを生成したいと思い
マイクロ秒＋乱数のようなIDで保存するのがセオリーみたいですが
乱数も時刻依存なので結局マイクロ秒レベルのオーダーだとかぶるおそれがある気がするので
Fuel 側でユニークなリクエストIDみたいなものがあったりしないでしょうか

あるいはどのAPもマイクロ秒で終了することは今のところないので
スレッドIDを取得するのでもいいのですが

よろしくおねがいします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Str の random メソッドが使えるのではないでしょうか。
http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/classes/str.html

```
// uuid (バージョン 4 - 擬似乱数)
Str::random('uuid');
// 返り値: f47ac10b-58cc-4372-a567-0e02b2c3d479
```

Comment: 確かに乱数でなくてもグローバル変数にカウンタをもてばいいだけですね。使わせていただきます！

Comment: 「グローバル変数にカウンタ」？！？！　そんな回答ではないですが。

Comment: すみません　そのリンクの中に increment っていうのがあったのでrandamよりそれを使えばいいかなと思った次第です　ちなみに Str::random の方はシードは何を使ってるんでしょうか　時刻なんだとしたら同じ問題になりますし C の rand のように呼ばれるたびに同じ系列を返すとしたら時間を自前でくっつける必要があります

Comment: 内部では mt_rand() を用いているようです。シードが被る可能性はあるのでしょうね。